# Extract filename from absolute path using Regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the filename with an extension from the absolute path using regex
for e.g.:-
`./app/txt.graphql`
`./txt.graphql`
`./test/app/bin/txt.graphql`

I wanna just get the full filename with an extension like- `txt.graphql` from the above path using regex

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're asking for "all the non-slash characters after a slash".

So you want this:

```
/([^/]+)$
```

and then you use the capture group.

The first slash is just a literal slash. `[^/]` means "non-slash character".  `+` means "one or more". `$` means "end of the string. And `()` wraps up the capture group.

I can't tell you how to get the capture group because you haven't said what tool or language you're using.